# VBA Formula can't copy the newest data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master sheet with some code on it

The first code is to allow me copy the first sheet only from a specified folder

The second one is to copy the data on column C & E based on column G (let's call this Copy Code)

After the Copy Code is created, I try to run it manually (F8) and automatically (using Private Sub) there's nothing wrong with it and It goes what I expected, but when I try to modify my data sheets, from the data directly or from the copied sheets on the master file, the code copy the data before the changes

here's my code

```
Sub Copy_Detail_Capex()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, MasterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim originalDestinationCell As Range, nextDestCell As Range
    Dim firstGreyCell As Range, c, e, s As Range
    Dim lastRow, firstRow, colToCheckLast, i As Integer
    Dim isMain As Boolean
    
    Set MasterSheet = Sheets("Form Rekap")            'where you want to put the copied data
    Set originalDestinationCell = MasterSheet.Range("C6") 'the first cell the data will be copied to
    Set nextDestCell = originalDestinationCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    
    firstRow = 6
    colToCheckLast = 7
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = MasterSheet.Name Then
            Set firstGreyCell = ws.Range("C" & firstRow) 'Set first starting loop cell
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, colToCheckLast).End(xlUp).Row
            isMain = True
            For i = firstRow To lastRow
                Set c = ws.Range("C" & i)
                Set e = ws.Range("E" & i)
                Set s = Nothing
                If isMain Then
                    If c.Interior.Color = firstGreyCell.Interior.Color Then
                        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                            Set s = c
                        Else
                            isMain = False
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If c.Interior.Color = firstGreyCell.Interior.Color Then
                        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                            Set s = c
                        End If
                        isMain = True
                    Else
                        If Not IsEmpty(e) Then
                            Set s = e
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                
                If Not s Is Nothing Then
                    Set nextDestCell = MasterSheet.Cells(nextDestCell.Row + 1, originalDestinationCell.Column)
                    nextDestCell.Interior.Color = s.Interior.Color
                    nextDestCell.Value = s.Value
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

What mistake that I made?

P.S. The code is not mine, I ask a colleague to make it for me, do please explain the code for me if possible

Thank you

Comment: Just a note: If you declare `Dim lastRow, firstRow, colToCheckLast, i As Integer` only `i` is of type `Integer` but all the others are `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it will be `Variant` by default. Also Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle so you need to use `Long`: `Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, colToCheckLast As Long, i As Long` • Check same for your other variables that have no type specified!

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What is the *"first code"* you speak about and what is the *"second code"*? I only see one code in your question. Also you say *"run it manually"* what exactly is *"it"* if there is 2 codes it which one is *"it"*. What do you mean by *"using Private Sub"* I see no `Private Sub` in your code. • Note that when you ask questions you need to be very precise with your wording. Otherwise it is very hard to get what you actually mean. • It may help to read [mcve] to [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ first thing first let me apologize for my unclear question cause I'm still pretty new to VBA. For the first code, I don't have any problem with it. It just, I want to clarify that I run 2 codes on a private sub which the codes come from 2 modules
the "it" on the second code is the code on my post. But, truly, thank you for the answer, so if I want to declare something, I need to specify one by one? and if the number of rows is unclear, I better use long than variant or integer?

Comment: No need to apologize: `Variant` is the worst type you can use it means it is *undefined* which type the variable is. Since Excel has more rows than fit into a `Integer` you would just run out of numbers if you loop through all rows in a sheet. Therefore you have to use `Long` which can hold enough numbers for the amount of rows. • Still a bit unclear Can you [edit] your question and add the codeparts needed to reproduce your issue. Explain detailed what you do (maybe screenshots help too) and explain what your code does versus what you expected it to do.